# Read the next line of a file I'm already reading

Tags: c++

Essentially I have a file that goes like this

```
Number of entries
Id
    Name of entry
    Float of entry
    Series of numbers
Id
    Name of entry
    Float of entry
    Series of numbers
```

For example, a file would look like this

```
4
0
    A. com
    0. 0
    1 2 3
1
    B. com
    0. 0
    0 3
2
    C. com
    0. 0
    0 1
3
    D. com
    0. 0
    1
```

Essentially what I want to do is to

- extract the first number, which tells me how many entries there will be.
- For that many times, extract the following
- Extract a string
- Extract a double
- Extract a series of numbers

I'm ok with the first few, but it's the last part that stumps me. I don't know how many numbers will be below the float. It could be one, two, or a hundred. Here is the code I've written:

```
ifstream ifile(filename);
    if(ifile.fail()){
        return false;
    }

    ifile >> num_of_webpages;

    for(int i=0; i < num_of_webpages; i++){
        Page temp;
        ifile >> pageid;
        ifile >> page_URL;
        ifile >> pagerank;


        string myline;
        getline(ifile, myline);
        stringstream ss(myline);

        while(ss >> outgoing_link){
            temp.add_url_to_links(outgoing_link);
            cout << outgoing_link << endl;
        }
    }
```

I can't extract it line by line because the types I'm extracting aren't all the same. If I'm already extracting info from a file, how do I extract the next line, then use that to extract the numbers until the end of the next line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the mistake is here

```
    ifile >> pagerank;

    string myline;
    getline(ifile, myline);
    stringstream ss(myline);
```

You are assuming that after reading the `pagerank` that you are on the next line, but you aren't. So your `getline` will just read the rest of the line containing the pagerank, which has no numbers at all.

Adding an extra `getline` should solve the problem

```
    ifile >> pagerank;

    string myline;
    getline(ifile, myline); // move to next line
    getline(ifile, myline);
    stringstream ss(myline);
```

So would using `ignore`

```
    #include <limits>

    ifile >> pagerank;
    ifile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // move to next line

    string myline;
    getline(ifile, myline);
    stringstream ss(myline);
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction) for more info